# Sending files tcp/ip

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to send a message using visual studio c# protocol tcp/ip.
I successfuly connected to the server but when i try to send a text message from the client i get **unhandled exception:**

System.Exception : 'Cannot send data to a null TcpClient (check to see if Connect was called)'

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.WriteLineAndGetReply(txtmessage.Text, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    }
```

Need help !!

Comment: We need to know where you establish the connection and how.

Comment: Have you connected to the server?

Comment: What is `client`? What is `WriteLineAndGetReply`? We have no idea.